# Docker windows container setting the Time Zone does not seem to work

Tags: docker

Is it possilbe to set the timezone in a windows container which is based on  microsoft/aspnet:4.7.2.

From the documentation this should work by running the following command

```
docker run  -e TZ=Pacific/Honolulu -d -p 8000:80 --name <ContainerName>
```

but the date is not changed when I log into the container via the following commands

```
docker exec -it <ContainerName> powershell
```

Then run Get-Date from Powershell in the container, the date is set to the current date/time of Pacific Standard the time zone for the host machine, I would expect it to be that of Hawaii for the docker container.

The TZ environment variable in the list of environment variables is present in the container

```
gci env:*
```

and it is set to Pacific/Honolulu as expected.

Comment: 1 year later I bumped into the same issue, did you find anything related to this ? I'm now seeing this in win2019

Comment: No, I have not tried this with win2019 but it failed in win2016. We worked around this issue from the code side rather than the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to use tzutil command?

Method 1

Follows a example to use the comamnd, to set a Australia time zone.

tzutil /s "AUS Eastern Standard Time"

Method 2

On the HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\TimeZoneInformation , has all information related to timezone.

From a virtual or physical machine with the correct time zone, you can export the register and import to the container.

I hope that my answer help you.